# Using a Google Sheets button to switch tabs

Tags: google-sheets

I have made a "drawing" in Google Sheets. I want to use it as a button to switch to a particular tab. Is this possible? Would I need to write a script for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Just write the following simple script in your script editor and assign it to your image by right clicking on it.

```
function go2PriceTab() {
  goToSheet("Price List"); 
  }

function goToSheet(sheetName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);}
```

*(Of course you can change the script name `go2PriceTag` to whatever you like)*

**As an alternative to a script:**

You can also use the **<kbd>F5</kbd>** shortcut and write the tab name in the field.
Just make sure you have enabled it beforehand.

[image]

If you do not want to enable the shortcuts, use the help menu where you type `Go to range` for the pop-up to appear.
You then write the tab's name and hit **<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need a script. It's not possible using simple options.